# Spring Integration message polling

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-messaging

I have a Spring configuration setup for polling messages from a db queue:

```
<int:annotation-config default-publisher-channel="messageChannel" />

<task:executor id="messageTaskExecutor" pool-size="1"
    queue-capacity="1" rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS" />

<int:transaction-synchronization-factory id="syncFactory">
    <int:after-commit expression="@messageSessionStore.removeFromIdCache(headers.id.toString())" />
    <int:after-rollback expression="@messageSessionStore.removeFromIdCache(headers.id.toString())" />
</int:transaction-synchronization-factory>

<bean id="messageQueryProvider"
    class="org.springframework.integration.jdbc.store.channel.OracleChannelMessageStoreQueryProvider" />

<bean id="messageSessionStore"
    class="org.springframework.integration.jdbc.store.JdbcChannelMessageStore">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="channelMessageStoreQueryProvider" ref="messageQueryProvider" />
    <property name="tablePrefix" value="QUEUE_" />
    <property name="usingIdCache" value="true" />
</bean>

<int:channel id="messageChannel">
    <int:queue message-store="messageSessionStore" />
</int:channel>

<int:poller id="defaultPoller" fixed-delay="500" max-messages-per-poll="1" task-executor="messageTaskExecutor" default="true">
    <int:transactional propagation="REQUIRED" synchronization-factory="syncFactory" isolation="READ_COMMITTED" transaction-manager="eosTransactionManager"/>
</int:poller>
```

However, the application runs on multiple nodes. When the server is restarted, it seems to happen that messages are picked up by more than 1 node (the nodes are all shut down at once and restarted in sequence). Is there any way to avoid multiple message processing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's somehow isn't possible using `OracleChannelMessageStoreQueryProvider`. Just because we rely there on the `FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED`. Therefore when `SELECT` is performed by one node, the records are locked and the next one will go to the next free rows in the table.

There is a not in the JavaDoc for the `setUsingIdCache()`:

```
 * <p>If using the provided {@link OracleChannelMessageStoreQueryProvider}, don't set {@link #usingIdCache}
 * to true, as the Oracle query will ignore locked rows.</p>
```

But I think it's fully unrelated. Removing that option and the `<int:transaction-synchronization-factory>` you will simplify your configuration, but the behavior must not be changed.

I think what you see is like `round-robin`: one node get a first row, the next one skip it and get the next one.

I somehow don't believe that different nodes get the same message when it is Oracle.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I think it might be a mix of one node already taking the message and partially doing the calculations, and saving data in our db (with seperate transactions) and then rolling back the message transaction when the node goes down. Then another node picks it up when restarting, doing again the same processing. So I guess more of an issue with our own handling of the message then.